# Trouble running phpMyAdmin on windows 10 and Apache2

Tags: phpmyadmin

```
OS Windows 10
Apache/2/4.27 (Win64)
Apache Lounge VC15 Server built: jul 7 2017 12:46:00
PHP 7.1.8 (cli)
```

I installed Apache2, and PHP stand alone, not through a package like XMAPP or WAMPP.

When type php -v from a command prompt, I get the correct version, so php is running. The PHP directory is in c:\php and I added it to the environment path.

When I type httpd -v, I get the correct version, so Apache is running (though I need to be in the c:\apache24\bin directory, as I did not add this to my environment path)

I installed phpmyadmin, by unzipping the current release, into the phpmyadmin folder, inside the htdocs folder.

If I type, in a browser, http://locahost, I get the "It Works", which is correct as this is what they index.html file in htdocs says.

When I tried http://localhost/phpmyadmin, I got a listing of the files in the phpmyadmin directory.

I modified the apache config file, and added:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>
```

the config file, is loading (earlier) the dir_module:

```
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
```

Then restarted the apache server (httpd -k restart).

When I did http://localhost/phpmyadmin, I saw a listing of the index.php that's in the phpmyadmin folder.

Any ideas on what I should be trying?

Comment: Getting a response from "php -v" does not mean anything is "running". You are calling a php executable which reports its version number. I suspect your Apache does not have mod_php installed or loaded.

Comment: Yes, using the term "running" is not correct. What I should have said is that php is installed and accessible. I solved the problem, and will publish the solution.

Comment: Your solution was to add mod_php?

Comment: See my edit, with the solution added

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper Please don't edit a solution into your question; post it as an answer instead.  Thanks!

Comment: You deleted it, instead of commenting, so I can copy it and paste it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add the following to the httpd.conf file:

```
# Adding php7 support
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
LoadModule php7_module "c:/php/php7apache2_4.dll"
PHPIniDir "c:/php"
```

and restart apache2 server